# Find the envelope of the solution of $ \ y''+y= \cos (a x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(i) Find the envelope of the solution of $ \ y''+y= \cos (a x)$

(ii) Find the solution if $ a \ \to 1 \ $

**Answer:**

The general solution is

$ y(x)=A \cos x+B \sin x+ \frac{x}{2a}sin (ax) \ \ $

The envelope is obtained by

$ y=0 \ \ and \  \ y'=0 \ $

Thus,

$ A \cos x+B \sin x+\frac{x}{2a} \cos (ax) =0 , \\ -A \sin x+B \cos x-\frac{x}{2} \sin (ax)=0 \ $

Now solving,  we get  values of $ A , B \ $

Substituting the values $ A , B \ $ in the general solution , we will get the envelope .

**Am I right ?**

(ii)

If $ a \to 1 \ $ , then  **how can I determine the particular integral ?**

Is it

$ P.I.=\frac{1}{D^2+1} \cos (ax) =\lim_{x \to 1 } \frac{1}{D^2+1} \cos (ax) \ $

But how to find the limit.

Comment: $$\left(\frac x{2a}\sin(ax)\right)''+\frac{x}{2a}\sin(ax)=\cos(ax)+\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac1a-a\right)\sin(ax)$$ So it is not a solution unless $a=(\pm)1$.

Comment: If $ a \to 1 \ $ , then what will be the solution specially the particular integral ?  can you please help me .